# Flash - stop animation from looping

Tags: flash, animation, actionscript, actionscript-2, banner

I've got a Flash banner on which I need some elements to animate when you rollover their parent, then stop, then run a different animation when you rollout. This works fine as long as the user behaves themselves, but if you jiggle the mouse so there's several rollover/rollouts in quick succession, it throws the animation into an endless loop. Has anyone else run into this problem?

My action script is:

```
on (rollOver) {
    //frames 2 - 10 are the "turn on" animation
    this.gotoAndPlay(2);
    //frames 11 - 25 are house_three's "turn on" animation
    _root.house_three.gotoAndPlay(11);
}
on (rollOut) {
    //frames 11 - end are the "turn off" animation
    this.gotoAndPlay(11);
    //frames 26 - end are house_three's "turn off" animation
    _root.house_three.gotoAndPlay(26);
}
```

house_three (in this case) has `stop();`s on frames 10, 25 and the last frame, and the current object has `stop();`s on frames 1, 10 and the last one, so it shouldn't play past those in any case.

I figured it might be something to do with many instances of the animation being queued up, but that would make the animation run a number of times and then stop (right?), but it seems to be running infinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a test inside your rollOver and rollOut to see if the banner is currently playing. If it is, stop it, then play.

```
if(this.isPlaying)
{
    this.stop();
    this.gotoAndPlay(2)
}
```

Comment: I figured out the problem. To minimise file-size, I was using actionscript "pause, then play" functions inside my movie objects, and it was those pauses which were getting queued infinitely. Once I removed those and just duplicated identical frames for seconds at a time, it worked fine. Thanks for your help though, I think this solution probably would have done it too (can't check, got rid of the bad code as soon as I found a solution).